# Routing URL's containing a pound symbol in CakePHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, routes, url-routing

For example, when I enter example.com/#hello/view/123 in my browser it will take me to example.com.  Everything after the # is ignored.

How can I create a Route in CakePHP to handle a URL with a hash in it?

Comment: That would be normal behaviour. Why do you need a hash?

Comment: I need to use a hash because the content on my site is dynamic.  My issue is when my users want to share a link, and they copy the url from the browser.  Since the shared link has a hash in it, it will not direct the user to where they think the link will take them.

Comment: Can You show Your array link?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'array link'.  I found a solution to my problem from the following tutorial: [http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/](http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/) The solution I found is to use the HTML5 history.pushState() function to change the web URL for my dynamic content without a hash.

Answer (score 0):

The pound sign already has several functions in cakephp, but instead adding '#subdirectory' to your url, using '#' => 'subdirectory' would generate '#subdirectory' which you could actually use.
check out this link [here](http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/adding-anchors-to-cakephp-generated-urls)